# How to reconfigure SQLTransport based NServicebus in Asp.net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nservicebus

I am using NServicebus(version 4.6.3) with SQLTransport in my ASP.net web api project. I have different connectionstrings for the queues for different environments (Dev,QA,etc). My configuration looks like below:

```
public class BusConfigurator
{
    public static IStartableBus Bus { get; private set; }

    public static void DisposeBus()
    {
        if (Bus == null) 
            return;

        Bus.Shutdown();
        Bus.Dispose();
        Bus = null;
    }
    public static void InitializeServiceBus(string connectionString)
    {

        var configure = Configure.With()
            .DefineEndpointName("MyEndPoint")
            .Log4Net(new DebugAppender { Threshold = Level.Warn })
            .UseTransport<SqlServer>(connectionString)
            .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .SetDefaultTransactionLevel()
            .UnicastBus(); // Error is thrown here on second call

        configure.MyCustomSQLServerPersistence();            

        Bus = configure.CreateBus();


    }

    public static void StartBus()
    {
        Bus.Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
    }

}
```

I have a dropdown in the app so that the user can select the environment. Based on the selection, I want to reconfigure the bus. So, I call DisposeBus then pass the connection string to the IntializeServiceBus method followed by the startBus. It works first time but throws error below when it gets called again with different connectionstring:

***Unable to set the value for key: NServiceBus.Transport.ConnectionString. The     settings has been locked for modifications. Please move any configuration code earlier in the configuration pipeline
Source=NServiceBus.Core
Line=0
BareMessage=Unable to set the value for key:   NServiceBus.Transport.ConnectionString. The settings has been locked for  modifications. Please move any configuration code earlier in the configuration  pipeline***

Is NServicebus intended to be used/configured this way? (I am guessing probably not) If not then is there a workaround/different approach for this?

Comment: Id' say that in NServiceBus v4.x there is no way, other than recycle the web app, to invalidate/recreate the Configuration, don't know yet (I'm setting up a sample) if there is something to achieve that in v5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In V4 or below, there is no way to do it by normal human means. There is only one Bus per AppDomain. All of the configuration API is static, so if you try, you get exactly the problems you ran into.

By "human means", I mean that it might be possible to do something crazy with spinning up a new AppDomain within your process, setting up a Bus within that, and then tearing it down when you're finished. It might be possible. I haven't tried it. I wouldn't recommend it.

In V5, the configuration API is completely redesigned, is not static, and so this is possible:

```
var cfg = new BusConfiguration();

// Set up all the settings with the new V5 Configuration API

using (var justOneBus = NServiceBus.Bus.Create(cfg).Start())
{
    // Use justOneBus, then it gets disposed when done.
}
```

That's right. It's disposable. Then you can do it again. In your case you wouldn't want to put it in a `using` block - you would want to set it up somewhere, and when the dropdown gets switched, call Dispose on the current instance and rebuild it with the new parameters.

Keep in mind, however, that the Bus is still pretty expensive to create. It's definitely still something you want to treat as an application-wide singleton (or singleton-like) instance. You definitely wouldn't want to spin up a separate one per web request.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! Thank you. I have decided to change the design of the application so that I don't have rely on recreating the bus.